# Substituting a minus sign for a relevant value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I'd like to substitute 4- to 3.75, 3- to 2.75, 2- to 1.75 etc with a formula, but I couldn't find a way to reference the value of the cell that this info is in.

Comment: Create a table that "translates" your text to values (first column e.g. 4-, second column 3.75) and use the vlookup function

Comment: Would it be possible to have the data be substituted in the same cell? Let's say I input 4- to A1 and after I'm done it'll change to 3.75

Comment: No, it's no possible with formulae.

Answer (score 0):

When `A1` is `4-`, this will do.

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)-0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It tests for a `-` first and if found, reduces by 0.25

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1)="-",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")-0.25)
```